# Given inner parabola curve $y=0.1x^2$ and thickness $d$, find outer curve

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics, parabolic-pde

As illustrated in the picture, the thickness $d$ is known and the parabolic formula of the inner (red) curve is given, say $y = 0.1x^2$. Then, how to obtain the formula for the outer (green) curve?

I think the formula should be in this form: $y_2 = kx^2 - d$ but I have no idea how to derive the value of $k$.

Can anyone give me some hint?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: @cosmo5 Hi cosmo5, thank you so much, it's really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any point it $(t,at^2)$ on the parabola $y=ax^2$, the corresponding point on the outer curve is

$$x=t+d\sin \theta,\>\>\>\>\> y = at^2 -  d\cos \theta$$
where $\theta $ is the tangent angle at $(t,at^2)$, given by
$\tan \theta = y’ =2ax$. Thus, the outer curve is

$$x=t+\frac {2adt}{\sqrt{1+4a^2t^2}}, \>\>\>\>\>
 y= at^2- \frac d{\sqrt{1+4a^2t^2}}
$$

which is in a parametrized form with $t$ as the parameter. Note that it is no longer a parabola.